# Бот (Python, telebot) не отправляет сообщение

Tags: python, telebot

Начал осваивать Python, и посетила идея + необходимость создать бота в Telegram. Но он работает не так, как ожидается. До этого момента всё хорошо:

```py
def get_location(message):
    global location
    location = message.text
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, check)

def check(message):  # 6-ая строка
    global candidat
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{candidat}')  # 8-ая строка
```

Я ожидаю, что бот запишет в ранее объявленную строковую переменную `location` текст, отправленный пользователем боту, она обновится и далее, соответственно, обновится переменная `candidat`, в которую я записываю конкатенацию из других строковых переменных, в том числе из `location`, и бот отправит на проверку пользователю сообщение, но ничего не происходит. Что я делаю не так? Ну кроме того, что всё это делаю в Visual Studio. И я не пойму, почему вообще не выполняются 6-8 строки примера независимо от того, что я укажу в 8 строке. В Telegram это выглядит примерно так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще советую записывать в БД, потому что бота вы можете в любой момент выключить, а БД останется

Comment: @Чёткая Четырка
а есть возможность сделать без БД? Условно собрать ответы на 6-7 вопросов сохранить их в переменные, и вывести пользователю список значений переменных для проверки?

Comment: Да, я думаю, возможно